# What unit can be used to define "loudness" across multiple programs?

Tags: levels, volume

I am working on a project where third parties submit videos to our system for deployment. We would like to use a single reference level that would allow us to specify "loudness".

If we were to specify a range in dbFS, would the maximum level (0) be the same across all video editing programs running on end user machines? If not, is there a unit or combination of units we can use to convey the levels to vendors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The international consensus seems now established that loudness measure should be done according to [ITU R BS.1770](https://www.itu.int/rec/R-REC-BS.1770/en).

> Algorithms to measure audio programme loudness and true-peak audio
>   level

It is widely used for broadcast delivery specs.

There seems to be two main target levels : -23/-24 LUFS for broadcast, -16 LUFS for streaming.

The [EBU R128](https://tech.ebu.ch/loudness) is based on BS.1770 to which it adds a few other measures.
There are many commercial or free available tools to measure programs loudness.